# Encontrar arquivos no Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou colocando um arquivo xml dentro do projeto porém ele não esta sendo localizado pelo meu `XmlTextReader` onde no projeto devo colocar este arquivo e como posso encontrar o mesmo na pasta do emulador?

Estou a usar o Xamarin Android.

[image: Soluçao]

Comment: Onde você colocou este arquivo em seu projeto?

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa junto com as activitys

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode simplesmente adicionar um arquivo em qualquer lugar desta forma.

Diferente do Windows, onde se pode incluir arquivos em um projeto e ter eles copiados para a pasta do programa, no Android o programa deve conter tudo o que precisa em um único arquivo, o Apk, qualquer arquivo que estiver fora do Apk é de obrigação de seu programa saber baixar do local apropriado.

No seu caso o que pode ser feito é mover este arquivo para a pasta Assets, é nesta pasta que devem ficar qualquer arquivo que seu programa precise usar, e a Build Action (Ação de construção no Xamarin Studio em português) deste arquivo deve estar como "AndroidAsset", desta forma incluindo o arquivo dentro do Apk.

Se você abrir o arquivo AboutAssets.txt que vem por padrão no projeto dentro da pasta Assets você vai encontrar o seguinte exemplo de como acessar este arquivo

```
public class ReadAsset : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        InputStream input = Assets.Open ("my_asset.txt");
    }
}
```

O único detalhe é que assets são somente leitura, se você precisar que este arquivo seja alterado então você deve incluir o arquivo padrão nesta pasta e salvar as alterações em algum outro lugar, dai cabe ao seu programa sempre que for ler o arquivo primeiro verificar se já tem um arquivo salvo, se não tiver extrai dos assets.

Existe também uma limitação em versões antigas do Android, se não me engano do 2.3 pra baixo mas não me lembro a versão exata, em que ele não consegue ler arquivos com mais de 1mb nos Assets, acredito que não vá ser o seu problema, mas caso aconteça a única solução que encontrei foi quebrar o arquivo em vários arquivos de 1mb e depois extrair e juntar todos de volta.

Comment: O que eu faço, ta dando erro
C:\Users\Visita\Documents\Projects\TB\Tabela\aapt.exe: Error: Invalid resource directory name: "assets". (Tabela)

Comment: Quando você seleciona o arquivo e olha na janela de propriedades verifique se o Build Action (Ação de construção) está como AndroidAsset